# PySNMP : ImportError: No module named pyasn1.compat.octets

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I'm trying to use PySNMP on windows, but when I try to import cmdgen I see following Error:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
ImportError: No module named pyasn1.compat.octets
```

How can I solve this error, I also don't touched *init*.py

Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the latest pyasn1 package also installed on your system for the same Python version as pysnmp is installed.

Answer (score 3):

I met with the same mistake.

I copied the library from this link into the downloaded project dirctory and corrected the error

this link :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyasn1/