# Ansible delegation from the command line

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to retrieve some information from a cisco switch via snmp_facts module (yes pysnmp is installed on my ansible host). I keep getting this error:

`TASK [snmp_facts] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [10.1.1.1]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: Missing required pysnmp module (check docs)`

This is the command I am running:

> ansible 192.168.1.11 -m snmp_facts -a 'community=blah host={{ inventory_hostname }} version=v2c' -k

From playbooks I wrote earlier, I used delegate_to: localhost but haven't been successful, it doesn't look like a valid option

Comment: What if you just run the task on `localhost`?  `ansible localhost -m snmp_facts ...`?  Specify the actual hostname rather than using `inventory_hostname`.

Comment: Same result: #ansible localhost -m snmp_facts -a 'community=blah host=192.168.1.11 version=v2c TASK [snmp_facts]
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: Missing required pysnmp module (check docs)                                    # sudo yum install pysnmp
package pysnmp-4.2.5-2.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

> pysnmp is installed on my ansible host

If that's true, you'll need to have ansible run that module using the python that contains `pysnmp`, not the one that is running ansible (as they can, and very often are, different)

It's close to what @larsks said:

```
ansible -c local -i localhost, \
    -e ansible_python_interpreter=/the/path/to/the/pysnmp/python ...
```

Comment: What is the actual file within pysnmp directory called? Here's what I am seeing:sh-4.1$ ls
cache.py   cache.pyo  debug.py   debug.pyo  error.py   error.pyo    __init__.pyc  nextid.py   nextid.pyo  smi
cache.pyc  carrier    debug.pyc  entity     error.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyo  nextid.pyc  proto
-sh-4.1$ pwd /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysnmp

Comment: The correct test is to see that it actually loads, such as `python2.6 -c "import pysnmp"` and then, assuming that works, set `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2.6` or whatever.

Comment: First test worked, specifying the interpreter did not and threw the same error previously seen.

Comment: It's possible the `pysnmp` is too old or something; can you execute [this import](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.2/lib/ansible/modules/net_tools/snmp_facts.py#L170) and see what happens?

Comment: python2.6 -c "from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen"           returns "Import Error: No module named compat.octets"                       
python2.6 -c "import cmdgen" returns error: "No module named cmdgen"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303512/pysnmp-importerror-no-module-named-pyasn1-compat-octets